# Should DTO attributes be started Capital letter in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```cs
public class CreateParams
{
  [Required]
  public string Number { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

All of codes that I found on the online starts capital letter when they make attributes.
I've found that even they started capital letter, Names of parameters can be started lower letter. 
I don't know what is right way to make attributes name.

Comment: just follow the standard convention of C#, property names should start with a capital letter (actually the whole name should follow the PascalCase).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is Yes. You can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions?redirectedfrom=MSDN) will give you more context behind it why to use PascalCase based attributes/properties/field names in C#. I have copied excerpt for you. For parameters you should you camelCase

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter
> names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including
> acronyms over two letters in length), as shown in the following
> examples:
>
> PropertyDescriptor HtmlTag
>
> A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters
> are capitalized, as shown in the following identifier:
>
> IOStream
>
> The camelCasing convention, used only for parameter names, capitalizes
> the first character of each word except the first word, as shown in
> the following examples. As the example also shows, two-letter acronyms
> that begin a camel-cased identifier are both lowercase.
>
> propertyDescriptor ioStream htmlTag
>
> ✔️ DO use PascalCasing for all public member, type, and namespace
> names consisting of multiple words.
>
> ✔️ DO use camelCasing for parameter names.